# SQLite foreign key to get value from another table

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, android-adapter, simplecursoradapter

so I hace 3 tables:

proveedor:
_id
descripcion

almacen:
_id
descripcion

Cab_ing
_id
descripcion
cod_proveedor
cod_almacen
 FOREIGN KEY(cod_proveedor) REFERENCES proveedores(_id)
 FOREIGN KEY(cod_almacen) REFERENCES almacenes(_id)

when I execute this query:

```
                 c = db.rawQuery(
                        " SELECT "
                        + "a."+KEY_ROWID + " AS _id,"
                        + "a.cod_agencia AS cod_agencia" + ","
                        + "a.fecha AS fecha" + ","
                        + "b.descripcion AS cod_proveedor" + ","
                        + "c.descripcion AS cod_almacen" + ","
                        + "a.estado AS estado" + ""
                        + " FROM " 
                        + "cab_ings a, proveedores b, almacenes c" 
                        +" WHERE a.cod_proveedor = b._id AND a.cod_almacen = c._id",null);
```

it doesn't show anything but WHEN I chance de "b._id" to '0' for example it shows. 
I dunno why, but I think is the reference problem.

EDIT:

I want the value (descripcion) of both tables thats why I use the traditional query a.id1 -> b.id AND a.id2 -> b.id

Proveedor table

```
ID      descripcion
1       R*1005
2       R*10335
```

Almacen table

```
ID      descripcion
3       a*10
6       a*12
```

Cab_ing table

```
ID      cod_proveedor   cod_almacen
1          1                 3
2          2                 3
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be; "where b._id = a.cod_proveedor and c._id = a.cod_almacen"?

Comment: no, still the same. b._id and c._id are the issues :S

Comment: Can you show a few lines of sample data? I'm confused about the search meaning.

Answer (score 0):

it might have something to do with the way you're referencing the primary keys of the `Proveedor` and `Almacen` tables. in your sample DDL the field are named `ID`, but in the join there's a reference to the `_id` field. (might that be referring to the alias in the `select`?)

i've created the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE "Proveedor" ("ID" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL , "descripcion" VARCHAR)

CREATE TABLE "Almacen" ("ID" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL , "descripcion" VARCHAR)

CREATE TABLE "Cab_ing" ("ID" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL , "cod_proveedor" INTEGER, "cod_almacen" INTEGER)
```

... and subsequently inserted the same test data you specified above. using this query:

```
select 
    cab.ID as _id,
    pro.descripcion as cod_proveedor,
    alm.descripcion as cod_almacen
from 
    Cab_ing cab
        inner join Proveedor pro on cab.cod_proveedor = pro.ID
        inner join Almacen alm on cab.cod_almacen = alm.ID
```

... i get two rows returned:

1. ID=1, cod_proveedor=1, cod_almacen=3
2. ID=1, cod_proveedor=2, cod_almacen=3

Comment: well I'm managing cursors so my table id need to be the prefix '_ID'  as said too when I change the  "b._id" to 0 it show the data. If you see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313987/do-i-have-to-use-id-as-a-sqlite-primary-key-and-does-it-have-to-be-an-int-an it says that too

Comment: have you looked at the data that's actually in the table?

Comment: yes I have two rows inserted in cab_ings and it shows in the listview when I change cab.cod_proveedor= 0 AND cab.cod_almacen = 0