# how to change listview data on spinner selection?

Tags: listview, arraylist, android-sqlite, spinner, android-spinner

i have a spinner and a listview in a view. data is coming in both from sqlite .
spinner data is coming from category table(Cid, Cname) Cname is to show in spinner and listview data is from Items table(Iid, Iname, Cid) Iname is to show in listview. cid is foreign key in items table .when spinner selection change i want to change listview data.this is what i have done so far..
below is my spinner with Cname populated from sqlite

```
      spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {                                                    dbRepo = new DBRepo(getApplicationContext());                    
            String pos = (String) parent.getSelectedItemPosition();              
            String cid =   dbRepo.getId(pos);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), cid, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            final ArrayList<Support> list = dbRepo.getItems(cid);

                adapter = new Custom(Category.this, R.layout.view_entry, list);

                lv.setAdapter(adapter);                  
               adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

this is the code to get cid of selected item in spinner

```
public  String getId(String selected) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT Cid from Catogeries where Cname=\"" + selected+ "\"";
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    String s = null;

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            s = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Cid"));

        }
    }
    c.close();
    db.close();
    Log.e("CID", " " + s);

    return s;
}
```

this is the method to get data in listview from db

```
 public ArrayList<Support> getItems(String cid){
   ArrayList<Support> list = new ArrayList<Support>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
  // Cursor c = db.query(TABLE_ITEM, new String[]{KEY_IID, KEY_INAME, KEY_CID}, KEY_CID + "=?", new String[]{cid}, null, null, null,null);
    String select = "SELECT * from items_table where Cid = "+cid;
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(select, null);
    String res;
    int j = c.getColumnIndex(Support.KEY_INAME);
    if(c.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            Support item = new Support();
                    item.setItemID(c.getString(0));
                    item.setItemName(c.getString(1));
                    item.setCategoryID(c.getString(2));
                    list.add(item);
        }while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    c.close();
    db.close();
    return list;
}
```

now cid is showing in toast but after passing cid to getitems() to get items nothing showing in listview.cid is showing in getItems() in log

```
   public ArrayList<Support> getItems(String cid) {
    ArrayList<Support> itemlist = new ArrayList<Support>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Log.e("CID is", cid);
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_ITEM;
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (c != null) {
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            Support item = new Support();
            item.setItemID(c.getString(0));
            item.setItemName(c.getString(1));
            item.setCategoryID(c.getString(2));
            itemlist.add(item);
        }
    }
    c.close();
    db.close();
    return itemlist;
}
```

the above code is showing items without passing cid but when i pass cid listview is showing empty and their is no error showing in logcat

finally resolved my issue that was because of a space after cid using trim function while storing data fetched from webservice to sqlite has done for me

Comment: getId is throwing nullpointerException

Comment: This may helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313987/do-i-have-to-use-id-as-a-sqlite-primary-key-and-does-it-have-to-be-an-int-an

Comment: thanks for your reply i will check that

Comment: no that is about cursurAdapter i am not using cursuradpater

Comment: @John Joe now check the code

Comment: can you check whether the id is passed in getItems method ?

Comment: @John Joe yes i check that in log id is showing in log

Comment: why you have two ?  `Support support = new Support( );` and 
            `Support item = new Support();`

Comment: no that is removed already from code and i have also update my code here now check that

Comment: @murtazaali check my answer

Comment: your above code got show anything ?

Comment: yes that is showing all items in listview

Comment: @John Joe now the problem is in query ???

Comment: did it display anything using this query? `Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(SELECT * FROM items_table WHERE Cid =? ",  new String[]  {cid}, null);` By looking at your latest code, where you initialize the `c` ?

Comment: no this is not displaying anything . and c is below the select query

Comment: @John Joe where is the problem please help me its urgent .....

Comment: use  `Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(SELECT * FROM items_table WHERE Cid =? ",  new String[]  {cid}, null);` and `String ID= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(YOUR_DatabaseHelper.id_column));`. Then add log, see ID display what

Comment: @John Joe i tried as you said but log is not showing in logcat

Comment: @John Joe log is not showing and their is no error showing in logcat but listview is still empty .....

Comment: @murtazaali I have no idea..sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public ArrayList<Support> getItems(String cid){
   ArrayList<Support> list = new ArrayList<Support>();
   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

  Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(SELECT * FROM items_table WHERE Cid =? ",  new String[]  {cid}, null);

   Support item = new Support( ); 
if(cursor!=null)
{
  while(cursor.moveToNext())
{
   String ID= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(YOUR_DatabaseHelper.id_column));
   // same with the others
   item.add(ID);
   list.add(item);
}
}
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return list;
}
```

Comment: i will check and inform you about the result of that and thanks for your help

Comment: item.add(ID) is showing error. and adding id to item.setItem(ID) and then list.add(item) is allowing but again listview is empty

Comment: just do a simple check, add `log.e("ID",ID)` after String ID, see what log display

Comment: i think cursor is empty log is not showing but a log on the top is showing the cid

Comment: what does `cid` display in getItems method ? Can you check ? _without passing cid is showing id's in logcat_ You mean ID get displayed?